# Why is there no closed-form equation for XIRR?

Tags: returns

Everything I have read about XIRR (e.g., as calculated in Excel) says that there is no closed-form equation and it must be calculated by iterated approximation.

Could someone give a brief mathematical explanation of why there is no closed-form solution?

Answer (score 3):

The *internal rate of return* is simply the rate at which the *net present value* is zero. So solve for $r$ in

$$
\sum{\frac{C_n}{(1+r)^n}} = 0
$$

There is no closed-form solution to this.

Comment: It would be good to get a mathematical explanation of *why* there is no closed-form solution, but OK